# When cppreference says that * should be overloaded as a free function for "symmetry", does "symmetry" mean commutativity?

Tags: c++, c++17, operator-overloading, commutativity

I have implemented a class `vec3`:

```cpp
struct vec3 {
    double x = 0, y = 0, z = 0;
    auto& operator*= (double d) {x *= d; y *= d; z *= d; return *this;}
};

auto operator* (const vec3 &a, double d) {auto ret = a; ret *= d; return ret;}
```

However, expressions of the form `vec3{} * 5.` compile, while expressions like `5. * vec3{}` do not. This confuses me, because [cppreference](https://v) says that

> **Binary operators are typically implemented as non-members to maintain symmetry** (for example, when adding a complex number and an integer, if operator+ is a member function of the complex type, then only complex + integer would compile, and not integer + complex).

Here, I *have* implemented `operator*` as a non-member, so shouldn't both `vec3{} * 5.` and `5. * vec3{}` compile, due to the symmetry mentioned in the cppreference quote?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the quote you provided means "if it is implemented as a member there is no way to maintain symmetry" rather than the "if it is implemented outside of the class it is *automatically* symmetrical" like you read... You still need T1_op_T2 and T2_op_T1 versions (which you can't have with members of T1 class) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60793466/arguments-order-in-overloaded-operators-in-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Implicit conversion symmetry of operator overloads

What cppreference means when it says "symmetry" is symmetry of implicit conversions. When you implement `*` as a member function, the left hand side is not subject to user-defined conversions. For example,

- a `vec2::operator*` member function wouldn't be usable by `vec3` on the left hand side, even if `vec3` was convertible to `vec2`; however,
- a `vec2::operator*(vec2)` could still accept a `vec3` on the right hand side if there was a `vec3 -> vec2` conversion

This means that `vec2 * vec3` and `vec3 * vec2` work differently, and such asymmetry is surprising and undesirable.
Similarly, the cppreference example `complex + integer` should work the same as `integer + complex`, assuming there is an implicit conversion from `integer` to `complex`. This would require `+` to be implemented as:

```cpp
complex operator+(complex, complex);
```

If there was a member function `complex::operator+` instead, `integer + complex` would be impossible.

#### Commutative operator overloads

The "symmetry" you're referring to is commutativity, i.e. the ability to swap the operands and yield the same result for some operation. C++ doesn't make operators commutative by default. It wouldn't be safe to do so for most anyway, especially not for `*`. Matrix multiplication isn't commutative, but uses the `*` symbol for example.

If you want commutativity, you'll have to do it yourself:

```cpp
auto operator*(const vec3 &a, double d) { auto ret = a; ret *= d; return ret; }
auto operator*(double d, const vec3& a) { return a * d; }
```

Similar to the `complex` and `integer` example, you could avoid writing these operator overloads if there was a conversion from `double` to `vec3`. However, this conversion is likely undesirable in your example.

Note that since C++20, `!=` and `==` are commutative even when overloaded. This is an exception to the rule that you have to define commutativity yourself.